# Graphite/Grafana - Find when a particular metric tooks longer than X seconds

Tags: grafana, graphite, graphite-carbon

Suppose that I export a particular metric from my application to Graphite every 10 seconds. If my application goes unavailable this metric won't be registered in Graphite for some time. After the application is back I would like to see when and for how long my application was offline.

I was wondering in doing this by querying Graphite (could be done using Grafana as well) and finding, for a particular time range (let's say 24 hours), if there was any 'gap' between one timestamp and the next one in which their differences exceeds 10 seconds, what would represent an offline span.

Is this possible to do with Graphite/Grafana and if yes, can someone please give an example of the query? Thanks